# Conditional expectation of standard normal distribution variables

Tags: conditional-expectation

The question is: Let $\mathrm {X} $, $\mathrm Y$ $\sim$ $\mathcal N(0,1)$. Knowing that they're independent variables find $\mathbb E(X^4+Y^3|X+Y)$

I did: $\mathbb E|X|=\mathbb E|Y|<\infty$,  therefore  $\mathbb E(X|X+Y)=\mathbb E(Y|X+Y)=\frac{X+Y}{2}$, and hence I came up with an idea that: 
$$\mathbb E(X^4+Y^3|X+Y)=\mathbb E(X^4|X+Y)+\mathbb E(Y^3|X+Y)=(\frac{X+Y}{2})^4+(\frac{X+Y}{2})^3$$
However this seems quite trivial and I am afraid I am making some obvious mistakes. I'd be really grateful if somebody could check it (and maybe show some hints how to do it proberly given that my reasoning is wrong)

Answer (score 1):

The mistake you're making is that $E[X^4|X+Y] \neq E[X|X+Y]^4$. So you're right, it's not that trivial.

I'm not too sure on how to solve the problem entirely. One approach that may work is that $E[f(Z) | Z] = f(Z)$, and you may be able to use $E[(X+Y)^3|X+Y]$ in a clever way to simplify some terms out.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a hard way :) Let $Z=X+Y$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    X \\
    Y \\
    Z 
\end{bmatrix}\sim \mathcal N\Bigg(\begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    0 \\
    0 
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 2 
\end{bmatrix}\Bigg)$$

So,

$$X|Z\sim \mathcal N(\mu_X+\frac{\sigma_X}{\sigma_Z}\rho_{XZ}(z-\mu_Z),(1-\rho_{XZ}^2)\sigma_X^2)=\mathcal N\bigg (\frac{1}{2}z,\frac{1}{2}\bigg)$$ $$Y|Z\sim \mathcal N\bigg(\frac{1}{2}z,\frac{1}{2}\bigg)$$

Then,

$$E[X^4|Z]=\bigg(\frac{z^2+6}{4}\bigg)^2-\frac{3}{2}$$
$$E[Y^3|Z]=\frac{z}{2}\bigg(\frac{z^2+6}{4}\bigg)$$

Finally,
$$E[X^4+Y^3|Z]=\bigg(\frac{z^2+z+6}{4}\bigg)^2-\bigg(\frac{z}{4}\bigg)^2-\frac{3}{2}$$